# mvn compiler:testCompile without compiling sources

Tags: java, maven

I'd like to be able to run tests for a maven project without recompiling the source. Is this possible?

I've pushed a project snapshot to a central location, and would like to have the test server build and run the test classes using the precompiled src classes. Is there a way to do this without making the tests a different module?

Comment: generally sources needs to be recompiled because test class generally consumes sources

Comment: If I can pull the compiled jar from a maven repo won't that already have the compiled src?

Comment: I've never seem this kind of situation before. As @JigarJoshi said "generally sources needs to be recompiled" I think that there isn't a module or plugin that can do it. Maybe you can create your own to attend this kind of situation. But I still think that is very odd for a number of reasons.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to save time. I have a release candidate jar where the tests have already been run, but I want to double check. Since the release candidate has already been compiled, I don't want to recompile it.

Comment: So if it was alredy tested there is no need for a double check, but that is my opinion. So try this: `mvn test` I'm not sure if it will build or not.

Comment: That will rebuild the src.

Comment: Why are you double checking the test results? Don't you trust the first run? Why not? What is your underlying concern? What you're asking is possible, just very bad practice, so maven makes it really hard.

Comment: It's on a test server that will run integration tests as well. Since it is possible that someone could have skipped the test before publishing it would be nice to verify that they pass along with other tests.